# duplicate entry error in mysql - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hey guys i have an error of duplicate entry in database . . whereas data can be duplicate..error is like

`Duplicate entry 'Years-1' for key 'term_type'`

the insert code is

```
INSERT INTO tbl_investment (member_id, investment_type, scheme_name, term, term_type, receipt_count, `investment_amount`, investment_date, maturity_amount, maturity_date) 
VALUES ('162', 'RD', 'hgyuuy', '2', 'Years', '1', '15000', '2013-04-11', '1000', '2013-04-11')`
```

Comment: term_type is set as unique so inputing multiple rows with the same value is impossible thus the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

term_type is set as unique so inputing multiple rows with the same value is impossible thus the error!

Comment: but all fields are uniqe then why in other fields dont occur such error . . @iTroubs